# How to develop tiles like components in wxpython GUI?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been building a scanner which have multiple scans. I wanted to list them in grid or tiles similar to attached image. One approach I am trying is to make Panel class of each tile. But as there are thousands of scan(tiles) I m concerned about speed and efficiency of program. Design is motivated by this.

[image]

Comment: You will need to be more specific and perhaps, share the code that you have tried so far. Even with the example screen shot you have chosen, I suspect that it is is divided into pages, with a maximum number of images per page, which you can scroll through. I suggest that you emulate that for speed and efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I've created a class inherited from wx.Panel which will contain a centered image, text and button. In this class, I've created the necessary methods to initialize the panel each time: SetImage, SetText and SetButton. Then, from the main frame class, I initialize several TilePanels to display them.

Finally, I set the same event handler for the button in the main class.

In the case you propose, the trick is in these 2 sizers: [wx.BoxSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BoxSizer.html) and [wx.WrapSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.WrapSizer.html)

Take a look at this code (In this case I use a wxWrapSizer because I want the panels to show below each other if they don't fit horizontally):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx
from wx.lib.expando import ExpandoTextCtrl, EVT_ETC_LAYOUT_NEEDED


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MainFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((690, 340))
        
        
        
        # Create 3 new panels:
        newPanel = TilePanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        newPanel.SetImage(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_INFORMATION, wx.ART_MESSAGE_BOX, size=wx.Size(80,80)))
        newPanel.SetText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla justo ut ante laoreet consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.")            
        newPanel.SetButton("View More...", callback=self.OnMyCustomHandler)

        newPanel2 = TilePanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        newPanel2.SetImage(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_WARNING, wx.ART_MESSAGE_BOX, size=wx.Size(80,80)))
        newPanel2.SetText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla justo ut ante laoreet consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.")            
        newPanel2.SetButton("View More...", callback=self.OnMyCustomHandler)

        newPanel3 = TilePanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        newPanel3.SetImage(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ERROR, wx.ART_MESSAGE_BOX, size=wx.Size(80,80)))
        newPanel3.SetText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla justo ut ante laoreet consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.")            
        newPanel3.SetButton("View More...", callback=self.OnMyCustomHandler)
        
        self._panels = []                         
        self._panels.append(newPanel)
        self._panels.append(newPanel2)
        self._panels.append(newPanel3)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("frame")               
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(220, 220, 220))        

    def __do_layout(self):        
        # Create a wrap sizer:
        sizer_1 = wx.WrapSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Add panels to the sizer:
        for panel in self._panels:
            sizer_1.Add(panel, 0, wx.ALL, 2)        

        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        
    def OnMyCustomHandler(self, event):
        print('{} has clicked'.format(event.GetEventObject().GetId()))        


# TilePanel Class
class TilePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.text_ctrl_1 = ExpandoTextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "No text set", style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.TE_CENTRE | wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL)
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "No button text")
        self.stBmp = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.sizer_flexi = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 1, 0, 0)
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()        

    def __set_properties(self):        
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        self.text_ctrl_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        self.text_ctrl_1.SetMinSize((200, -1))
        self.button_1.SetMinSize((100, 40))
        self.button_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))        

    def __do_layout(self):        
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer_flexi)
        self.sizer_flexi.Fit(self)
        self.sizer_flexi.AddGrowableRow(1)
        self.sizer_flexi.AddGrowableCol(0)
        self.Layout()
    
    def SetImage(self, bmp):
        self.stBmp.SetBitmap(bmp)
        self.sizer_flexi.Add(self.stBmp, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.Layout()        
        
    def SetText(self, text):
        self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue(text)
        self.sizer_flexi.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.Layout()

    def SetButton(self, btnTitle, callback):
        self.button_1.SetLabel(btnTitle)
        self.button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, callback)
        self.sizer_flexi.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        self.Layout()

# end of class TilePanel


# Main App:
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And this is the result:
[image]

If I had used a wx.BoxSizer instead, the panels would narrow when they don't fit. Try it!

Run, change and test this code until you understand it.

**P.D.: I highly recommend that you use wxGlade to design interfaces in wxPython. It will help you learn how sizers work much better than any tutorial.**

http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yeah I also worked around exactly like the way you mentioned here. Thank you for wxGlade suggestion too.